# If I set cmdheight=0 I get the "Press Enter or type command to continue" message

Tags: neovim

If I set my `cmdheight=0` then any action I perform like saving the buffer or opening a new buffer or anything trigger the `Press Enter or type command to continue` message.

It annoys me. I want to disable the apparition of the `Press Enter or type command to continue` message.

Comment: How about to then simply use `set cmdheight=1`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tweak [`shortmess`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27shortmess%27) to avoid the prompt as much as possible, for example I have it set to `csCFSW` which disables messages for:

- Ins-completion matches
- Search hit BOTTOM/TOP
- Ins-completion scanning sources
- File info when start editing
- Search count
- Written file

Still, `cmdheight` is still considered experimental, and you may find other annoying messages being shown. You may want to use a GUI, or (as I do) a plugin like [Noice](https://github.com/folke/noice.nvim), which handles most of the UI on a terminal

Comment: I get this weird issue where it reports an error every time i save the current opened buffer and it looks annoying in notify